# How to call an async fucntion in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm just trying to call an async function and when i get the return i want to display another view.

this is my index :

```
const UserService = require('JitApp/services/UserService.js');
class App extends Component {

  state = {
      isLoad: false
  }

  getUser = async function() {
    UserService.getUser().then( function(user) {
      let isLogged;
      if(user){
        isLogged = true;
      }else{
        isLogged = false;
      }
      this.setState({'isLogged': isLogged});
      this.setState({'isLoad': true});
    }
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    // ADD THIS THROW error
      throw error;
})
    );
  }.bind(this);

  render() {
    this.getUser();
    if(!this.state.isLoad){
        return(
          <ActivityIndicator
                animating={this.state.animating}
                style={[styles.centering, {height: 80}]}
                size="large"
              />
        );
    }else {
      if(this.state.isLogged){
        return(
          <Login />
        );
      }else {
        return(
          <Login />
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And there is my UserService :

```
var UserService = (function() {
    return {
        /**
         * Try to get user from the storage
         */
        getUser: () => {
            return AsyncStorage.getItem('@JIT:User').then(
                function(user) {
                    if(user){
                        return user;
                    }else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }.catch(function(error) {
                console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
                // ADD THIS THROW error
                throw error;
                })
            );
        },
        /**
         * Set user in the storage
         */
        setUser: (user) => {
            AsyncStorage.setItem('@JIT:User', user);
        },
    };
})();

module.export = UserService;
```

But when i run my code i get an warning :

```
YellowBox.js:69 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
UserService.getUser is not a function
TypeError: UserService.getUser is not a function
```

I would like to know why i get this error and how can i fix it

Comment: Looks like you're trying to access a property before it exists. async/await doesn't magically make things outside of said async function wait for a value.

Comment: i don't understand why, you mean that UserService is not define when i try to call it ? but the import is the first things done ...

Comment: well, no, you called getUser(), then later on in the same function you tried to access isLogged, which doesn't exist until getUser is complete. getUser won't complete until some time later.

Comment: I see, but the error is that getUser is not define ... And if we check the end we don't use isLogged var until the isLoad is false

Comment: you're right, what I described is a problem you'll have later, sorry.

Comment: It's seems that my service (UserService) is not really load and i don't know why ...

Comment: well, no that would have thrown a different error. The error is `UserService.getUser` is not a function. Where within index did you define `UserService`?

Comment: If you console.log UserService after you require it, do you get what you expect?

Comment: I edit my post to show you, but i require my service at the top of my view.
Actually when i log my UserService i get en empty object :s

Comment: I think it's because you're missing an `s` at the end of `module.exports` in your userservice file

Comment: Oh damn ... you right ... i'm juste tired ... thanks a lot